# Removing gap between select elements within table's tr

Tags: html, html-table

I have a `<table>` with many `<tr>`s. Within one `<tr>` I want to have two `<select>` elements. However when I try to do this the `<select>`s are pushed far apart from each other. I noticed that the gap appears when there are other `<tr>` elements added within the `<table>`. (If I had only the `<tr>` with the two `<select>` elements, the gap doesn't exist.) I have two jsFiddles below. One shows what it looks like with the gap, the other without. Any help would be much appreciated!

The jsFiddle showing the gap: http://jsfiddle.net/yMAW5/

The jsFiddle without the gap: http://jsfiddle.net/vyaHJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your second tr with this

```
<tr>
        <td class="label"><label>High School:</label></td>
        <td colspan="3">
           <input id="profile_high_school" name="profile[high_school]" size="32" type="text" value="Value" />
        </td>
     </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I just had to add colspan to the other `<td>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

That's because table's column width is inherited by the widest element in the whole column.